# ForbiddenException while creating mediaconvert job with aws java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, video-editing, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-media-convert

I want to use aws mediaconvert service for video stitching.
Have an paid account with AWS having access to mediaConvert service.
Able to create the video stitching JOB via mediaConvert console.
Now i am trying the same thing with AWS java SDK.
Assigned all the permissions to IAM user and created role for mediaConvert service.

While doing so, I am getting following error

**com.amazonaws.services.mediaconvert.model.ForbiddenException: You must use the subscription API to subscribe your account to the service before using this operation.**

*Stack Trace:*

```
com.amazonaws.services.mediaconvert.model.ForbiddenException: You must use the subscription API to subscribe your account to the service before using this operation. (Service: AWSMediaConvert; Status Code: 403; Error Code: ForbiddenException; Request ID: bba9a221-54b7-47cc-9e2a-88eeece245ea)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1726) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1381) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1127) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:784) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:752) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.mediaconvert.AWSMediaConvertClient.doInvoke(AWSMediaConvertClient.java:1874) ~[aws-java-sdk-mediaconvert-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.mediaconvert.AWSMediaConvertClient.invoke(AWSMediaConvertClient.java:1841) ~[aws-java-sdk-mediaconvert-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.mediaconvert.AWSMediaConvertClient.invoke(AWSMediaConvertClient.java:1830) ~[aws-java-sdk-mediaconvert-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.mediaconvert.AWSMediaConvertClient.executeCreateJob(AWSMediaConvertClient.java:333) ~[aws-java-sdk-mediaconvert-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.mediaconvert.AWSMediaConvertClient.createJob(AWSMediaConvertClient.java:304) ~[aws-java-sdk-mediaconvert-1.11.699.jar:na]
at com.learn.aws.controller.MediaConvertController.runMediaConvertJob(MediaConvertController.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to set up the correct Endpoint. 
Let me know if you are doing that, otherwise can you please try to run this command and get the correct endpoint for your specific AWS region and see if it will work as expected by setting up the endpoint in your AWS SDK code?

aws mediaconvert describe-endpoints  --region us-east-1 
ENDPOINTS   https://xxxxxxx.mediaconvert.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/apireference/getting-started.html